# SAP infoset table connection

Tags: abap, sap-query

I'm new in SAP and I have a question. I have an infoset that has 3 tables that contain customer information and shopping made.
Currently I get a report that contains the details about the customer and there is a column that indicates whether the customer bought during a certain sale . I get an offer date and check the table (not linked to the 3 tables) if that customer made a purchase on the date.

Now I have to do something more complicated. I have a date and time of sale, and I have to return a report that contains the names of all the customers, for customers who did buy during the sale, to register all the amounts they bought ( the sale is one hour in day for week)

That's what I get until now:

```
Customer 1 , id1 , x
Customer 2 , id2 , V
Customer 3 , id3 , x
```

This means that customer A actually bought in the sale. And now I have to get:

```
Customer 1 , id1 , x
Customer 2 , id2 , 30$, DateTime1
Customer 2 , id2 , 10$, DateTime2
Customer 2 , id2 , 15$, DateTime3
Customer 3 , id3 , x
```

My problem is that when I connect  the table with all the customers' shopping, I get every customer he has ever made. And if I do `CHECK` for the date and time condition all customers who have not bought the offer are deleted. I mean I only get the Customer 2.
I add the table as "left outer". What should I do ?

Comment: Give us the existing code.

Comment: IF ( BuyDateTime >= StartDateTime ) AND (  BuyDateTime <= EndDateTime ) .
      TT = 'L' .
   ENDIF.
   CHECK  TT = 'L' .

Comment: Read what is [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add complete code **into the question body**, not comment.